# Changing OS X 10.6.8 mouse pointer

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, cursor

I wish to know if there is any way to change OS X 10.6.8 cursor. I want to change it to "Hello Kitty" cursor, don't ask why, not my mac:)

Is it possible? How? What kind of cursor files are accepted?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Mighty Mouse](http://www.unsanity.com/haxies/mightymouse) a "haxie" for "Application Enhancer". Doing this might endanger the stability of your system, as it's using a mechanism that injects code into other programs.

While the web site says it only works for OS X 10.3 - 10.4, according to [this MacThemes thread](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=734251), it can be made to work on Snow Leopard by following [these instructions](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=734171#p734171). You can get the required beta version [from here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10883/mighty-mouse).